# How to call a private method from reactive subscribe of Mono and return a specific type in Spring 5?

Tags: mono, spring-webflux

I have a main method whose return type `WebClient`. In this method I get a `Mono` object and using subscribe I'm trying to call another method which returns webclient object. Now within subscribe, I have webclient object which I want to return. I'm blocked here as I'm not sure how to return the object and where to put the return keyword.

Main method:-

```
public WebClient getWebClientWithAuthorization(String t) {
-----
----

    Mono<AccessToken> accessToken = authenticationProvider.getUserAccessToken(serviceConnectionDetails, queryParams);

    Disposable disposable = accessToken.subscribe(
        value -> getWebClientBuilder(t, value.getAccessToken()),
        error -> error.printStackTrace(),
        () -> System.out.println("completed without a value")
    );

}
```

Below `getWebClientBuilder` method returns webclient object:-

```
private WebClient getWebClientBuilder(String tenantDomain, String accessToken) {
        //TODO Logic for Saving the Token using Caching/Redis mechanism will be taken up from here and implemented in future Sprints
        logger.info("Bearer token received: "+ CommerceConnectorConstants.REQUEST_HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_BEARER +" "+ accessToken);

        if (null != proxyHost) {
            return utilsbuilder.baseUrl(tenantDomain).filter(oauth2Credentials(accessToken)).clientConnector(getHttpConnector()).build();

        } else {
            return utilsbuilder
                    .baseUrl(tenantDomain)
                    .filter(oauth2Credentials(accessToken))
                    .build();

        }
    }
```

Now in `getWebClientWithAuthorization` method, where to put the return keyword inside subscribe or outside subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

## Think "Reactive" end to end

***In my opinion, what is the most important when star building application using Reactive Programming is treating any call as asynchronous hence providing end to end asynchronous and non-blocking communication.***

Thus, what I suggest you is providing instead of synchronous type a `Mono<WebClient>` in the following way:

```
public Mono<WebClient> getWebClientWithAuthorization(String t) {
-----
----

    Mono<AccessToken> accessToken = authenticationProvider.getUserAccessToken(serviceConnectionDetails, queryParams);

    return accessToken.map(value -> getWebClientBuilder(t, value.getAccessToken()))
                      .doOnError(error -> error.printStackTrace())
                      .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("completed without a value"))
    );

}
```

So, now you may easily map value to the `WebClient`'s instance and send it to the downstream. In turn, your downstream may react to that value and transform `WebClient` to the execution of HTTP call as it is shown in the following example:

```
getWebClientWithAuthorization("some magic string here")
        .flatMapMany(webClient -> webClient.get()
                                       .uri("some uri here")
                                       .retrieve()
                                       .bodyToFlux(MessageResponse.class))
        // operate with downstream items somehow
        // .map
        // .filter
        // .etc
        // and return Mono or Flux again to just continue the flow
```

And remember, just continue the flow and everywhere specify reactive types if async communication is supposed. There is no sense to `subscribe` to the source until you met some network boundary or some logical end of the stream where you do not have to return something back.